# Why is "while((String tmp=x))" not valid Java syntax?

Tags: java, syntax

I have a clarification about some Java code:

What's the difference between these codes, that one can be compiled while the other cannot.

I'm not interested on "how to fix the error" because I've already solved it, but more on an explanation about the problem:

### Working

```
public void  x(){
    HashMap<String , Integer> count= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Scanner scan= new Scanner("hdsh");

    String tmp;
    while((tmp=scan.next())!=null){
        if(count.containsKey(tmp)){
            count.put(tmp, 1);
        }
        else{
            count.put(tmp, count.get(tmp)+1);
        }
         tmp=scan.next();
    }

}
```

### Not Working

```
public void  x(){
    HashMap<String , Integer> count= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Scanner scan= new Scanner("hdsh");

    while((String tmp=scan.next())!=null){
        if(count.containsKey(tmp)){
            count.put(tmp, 1);
        }
        else{
            count.put(tmp, count.get(tmp)+1);
        }
         tmp=scan.next();
    }

}
```

### The errors of Eclipse are:

Multiple markers at this line:

- String cannot be resolved to a variable
- Syntax error on token "tmp", delete this token
- String cannot be resolved to a variable
- Syntax error on token "tmp", delete this token

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[JLS §14.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.12):

```
WhileStatement:
    while ( Expression ) Statement
```

[JLS §15.27](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27)

```
Expression:
    AssignmentExpression
```

[JLS §15.26](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)

```
AssignmentExpression:
    ConditionalExpression
    Assignment

Assignment:
    LeftHandSide AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression

LeftHandSide:
    ExpressionName
    FieldAccess
    ArrayAccess
```

`LeftHandSide` cannot be a declaration, so it is not allowed.

Comment: I am not even sure it makes it that far into the production rules .. but these rules do explain why the production is ultimately invalid. +1.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot declare a variable inside of an expression.  (except for the first part of a `for` loop)

Comment: The first part of a for-loop is either a LocalVariableDeclaration *or* a StatementList so it (not being able to have declarations inside expressions) is not even violated in that case..

Comment: That's correct, but I think the OP wants to know exactly why it isn't allowed.

Comment: thats correct, i'm intrested the question "why" as Silox has mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing for and while syntax.
The second block dont work because your declare tmp variable inside a condicion.

`while((String tmp=scan.next())!=null)`

try this:

`String tmp;
while((tmp=scan.next())!=null)`

Comment: i know how to fix it, but i want to understand the java syntax

Comment: The *try this* part is exactly what he has in his working example already!